# How to type Degree symbol (°) in Azure SQL data warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure, azure-sql-database

I have data source like this:

```
1°18'19.74"N
```

But when I insert it to Azure data warehouse it look like this:

```
1�18'19.74"N
```

Comment: what's the data source, csv or other table?

Comment: data source from csv

Comment: It looks like an encoding issue. I suppose the column is `nvarchar`? What is the encoding of the CSV?

Comment: @Irwan which tool or command did you use?

Comment: Yeah i just found that the 'nvarchar' make it like that. Thank you for your answer @HansKeﬆing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using Data factory copy the csv data to SQL DW,

[image]

[image]

[image]

It works well.

The Sink table schema and data after pipeline executed:

[image]

Please modify your sink table data type to varchar() and test again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Irwan,You're welcome! If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.